# Why ImageIO.write() method modifies pixel values?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to run a simple Java program that tries to do the following : Extract pixel data from a given image. Then use this data to create a new image of the same type. The problem is that when I read the pixel data of this created image, the pixel values differ from the ones I have written into it. This happens not only or .jpg images but also for some .png images(so it's not even restricted to image type). 
Here is my code:

```
package com.alex;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            // Read source image
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/field.png")); 


            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();
            int[] imagePixels = new int[width*height];
            img.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, imagePixels, 0, width);

            // Create copy image
            BufferedImage destImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType());
            destImg.setRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), imagePixels, 0, img.getWidth());
            File out = new File("D:/test.png");
            ImageIO.write(destImg, "png", out);

            // Extract copy image pixels
            BufferedImage copy = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/test.png"));
            int width1 = copy.getWidth();
            int height1 = copy.getHeight();
            int[] extractedPixels = new int[width1*height1];
            copy.getRGB(0, 0, width1, height1, extractedPixels, 0, width1);

            System.out.println("The 2 dimensions are " + imagePixels.length + " " + extractedPixels.length );

            // Compare the piels from the 2 images
            int k=0;
            for(int i=0; i<imagePixels.length; i++) {
                if(imagePixels[i] != extractedPixels[i]) {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of different pixels was: " + k);
            }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception was thrown during reading of image: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
}
```

Unfortunately quite often and impredictable the 2 images pixel data differ. Could someone please help me find a method so that, at least for an image type,  the values don't get modiied ?
*Edit* Here is an image that fails in the above process

[image: For this image the background color is changed]

Comment: What is this doing: `img.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, imagePixels, 0, width);` ?

Comment: @porfiriopartida, it fills imagePixels array with image pixel data

Comment: Using the image at http://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png, in a slightly altered version of that source, shows output.. `The 2 dimensions are 1024 1024
Number of different pixels was: 0`

Comment: `rgbArray if not null, the rgb pixels are written here` Got it.

Comment: Interesting, if you use the created one as input it will perform the exact copy, it should be doing a compression inside for PNGs.

Comment: Why do you create a copy of `img` in `destImg`? Why not just write `img` directly? You seem to assume that these images have the exact same RGB values. Can you verify if they have?

Comment: @haraldK : Well img and destImg are actually only BufferedImage's. img BufferedImage is obtained from the actual image and I use it to extract it's pixel data. In an ideal world I add values to some of the pixels in the resulted array(creating a new array with different values in some controlled positions) and then extract this info by substracting the target pixels. However the code above leaves all pixels intact(for simplicity). I use them with the second BuferedImage to ImageIO.write() a new image with theoretically identical pixel data. But when ead from this new image they change values

Comment: This offcourse means that I cannot add info to some pixels-> use them to create a new image -> extract pixels from new image later( i.e at reception) and then recover the info by doing destImgPixelAray[i] - imgPixelArray[i] (i - coded pixel values) because if for example destImgPixelAray[i] = imgPixelArray[i] + 5 = 155 at creation of destImg, when I read the coded image(created with destImgPixelArray) into a BufferedImage an call getRGB() on it destImgPixelAray[i] might difer from 155 (value at creation) and when I substract imgPixelArray[i] from it I might get 18 instead of 5(actually added)

Comment: If the API can't reliably getRGB() what I setRGB() then ofcourse there is no chance for further procesing. The code above only copies pixels to point out this shortcoming. I am sure there must be something that is missing here because I am ure that java can do far greater processing

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using the correct color model for reading and writing.

According to the [BufferedImage.getRGB() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29),

> Returns an array of integer pixels in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB color space, from a portion of the image data. Color conversion takes place if the default model does not match the image ColorModel. There are only 8-bits of precision for each color component in the returned data when using this method. With a specified coordinate (x, y) in the image, the ARGB pixel can be accessed in this way:

```
pixel = rgbArray[offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)];
```

**[Edit]**

You need to use the constructor `BufferedImage(width, height, type, ColorModel)`, as indicated in the [Javadoc for your image type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_BINARY) (`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`):

> When this type is used as the imageType argument to the BufferedImage constructor that takes an imageType argument but **no ColorModel argument, a 1-bit image is created** with an IndexColorModel with two colors in the default sRGB ColorSpace: {0, 0, 0} and {255, 255, 255}.
>
> Images with 2 or 4 bits per pixel may be constructed via the **BufferedImage constructor that takes a ColorModel argument** by supplying a ColorModel with an appropriate map size.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Isn't img.getType() in line: 
BufferedImage destImg = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getType()); 

assuring me that I have the same ColorModel for both BufferedImages ? Or is it the fact that I need to somehow etract the ColorModel from the actual file on the disk ? If so coul I o this ?

Comment: You might verify that their color models are the same using `getColorModel()` on the one read from disk and the one you created. Its possible that the images are the same visually with a different pixel arrangement or color model in code.

Comment: Unfortunately the ColorModdel is the same across all 3 BufferedImage's. But thanks for all the help so far guys. If you manage to find something out please help. Hint : Try using several png images to see what happens (sometimes it works other times it totally  fails)

Comment: @AlexandruMarianObaj Instead of us guessing, please attach or link some images that "fails" to your question.

Comment: @haraldK I added an image that fails. Most disturbing of all is the fact that it is a .png file (so no lossy compression like jpeg)

Comment: @WeaponsGrade Good catch in the edited version. Could very well be the issue. It's possible to use the constructor that takes a `ColorModel` and `WritableRaster` to avoid a special case for `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage(java.awt.image.ColorModel,%20java.awt.image.WritableRaster,%20boolean,%20java.util.Hashtable)

Comment: I tested the solution I listed using the Scala REPL with the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
First print same index in two array 
If the result is not same means your problem in your color mode, But if  same means your comparision is not work.